# Usar função do componente pai em componente filho em angular

Tags: angular, angular-6, angular-8

tenho tentando disparar uma função de um componente pai em um componente filho e não consigo, alguém já fez algo do tipo?

Comment: Provavelmente o que vc quer seja simples, mas, esteja fazendo de uma maneira errada!

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa criar um service. Utilize o comando ng g s /.

Feito isso, no seu service você vai colocar a lógica da sua função e importar ela no componente pai e filho da seguinte forma:

Service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EspecialidadeService {

  especialidadeVO: EspecialidadeVO;

  private url = `${environment.apiUrl}especialidade`;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
              private http: HttpClient,
              private router: Router
              ) { }

  getEspecialidade() {
    const body = {};
    return this.http.post<EspecialidadeVO>(this.url + 'pesquisa/pesquisar', body).pipe(take(1));
  }
```

Componentes pai e filho:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-especialidade-cadastro',
  templateUrl: './especialidade-cadastro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./especialidade-cadastro.component.css'],
  preserveWhitespaces: true
})
export class EspecialidadeCadastroComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);
  private id: number;

  constructor(
    private especialidade: EspecialidadeService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: any) => {
        this.id = params.id;
        if (this.id !== undefined) {
          const result = this.especialidade.especialidadeById(this.id);
          result.subscribe( res => {
            this.name.setValue(res.nomeEspecialidade.trim());
          });
        }
      }
    );

  }
```

Veja que no componente eu crio no construtor uma instância de EspecialidadeService com nome especialidade, depois no onInit utilizo o comando this.especialidade.especialidadeById, que é a função criada no service. Assim essa função fica visível para qualquer um que criar uma instância desse service.

Tem formas de você passar os parâmetros de um para o outro, mas você disse que quer acessar funções e não valores, a forma ideal em angular é utilizando services.